# Are there any benefits for going after non-lethal takedowns in Cyberpunk?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

For my first playthrough, I'm planning to play stealthily. I won't run and gun cause mayhem, but sneak around and take people down without alerting anyone. I've noticed when grabbing people, I have the option of doing a lethal, or non-lethal takedown.

**Is there any reason why I would want to choose the non-lethal option?**

I could utilize silent (and lethal) weapons and that will make things easy, but why would I want to go slower and stay non-lethal (other than for challenge)? Are there any perks that could level up staying non-lethal? Will I be able to turn the enemies later in the game for whatever reason? Will a boss character be more sympathetic to me if I left their minions alive? Or will I gain anything by ensuring everyone dies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are numerous missions (both story and side missions) that want you to go in silently and not kill anybody. These missions can still be completed loud but may have a different outcome - in the instances of side jobs this normally means you're missing out on a bonus payment for completing the job how the fixer wanted it fixing.

There are also numerous instances where killing somebody is then bought up later in conversation (as both a positive and a negative, depending on the conversation you're having) however this does not have a final impact on the endings available to you.

Answer (score 4):

I mean I'm 2-3 days in now. There is no XP difference if they live or die, there is no moral choice, or anything really. There are some missions that ask you do non-lethal takedowns but besides that nothing.

Answer (score 4):

If you do a non-lethal takedown then punch them in the head, you get double experience/street cred it seems.

Comment: I'll have to make it a habit to punch everyone in the head when I loot them after sniping them. :D

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm doing it wrong but I can't seem to trigger the extra xp/sc.

Comment: Apparently just hitting them again with anything as if they were still alive would do it. It seems to be just a bug all around.

Answer (score 3):

I mean, I think you have your answer. In a world where killing makes no difference, do you choose violence? From a roleplay perspective it matters. But if you only care about efficiency, my guess is killing is fast but makes a mess, so enemies may be able to spot severed limbs and spatters, thus raising an alarm. Non-lethal nets you some street cred, and from what I've noticed, allows you to get some more by just killing an unconscious enemy.